# How to convert an existing resource to terraform in azure

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-api-management

I have an `azure` APIM (API management) and I need to convert this to `terraform` code.

Is there a way I can do this? I tried `terraform import` but only it updates the `terraform state` and I can't get the terraform code. When I do a `terraform apply` it says, the resource definition is not found and it is going to delete it.

Can someone help me?
Thank you!

Comment: I just ran across this post: https://azure-in-action.blog/2018/04/24/azure-to-terraform-az2tf/

Answer (score 1):

there is no way of doing that. you'd need to create your definition from the existing resource and import the resource

Comment: That means I should create my own definition with the same features (parameters) as in the existing resource. If I miss something it is going to delete it from the actual resource right?

Comment: no, at least not before you import it. plan will always show its going to delete it

Comment: for what, exactly? before you start managing resource with terraform it won't do any changes to the resource. after you start managing it - just make sure the definitions match (or at least none of the read-only properties differ) and it won't delete the resource